# LinkProps is missing in next-intl/link (when migrating from next/link)

Tags: next.js, internationalization, react-typescript, next-link, next-intl

I used `LinkProps` to create custom `Link` wrappers and pass native props along with my custom ones. Pretty standard pattern:

```
import {type LinkProps} from "next/link";
import {type ImageProps} from "next/image";

export interface NavbarItemProps extends LinkProps {
  title: string;
  icon: ImageProps['src'],
}

// and then goes my component:
export function NavbarItem({ icon, title, ...props }: NavbarItemProps) {
  // ...
}
```

but once I migrated to `next-intl/link` - I found out that it doesn't export any `LinkProps`.
And old `LinkProps` is incompatible with the new `Link` component from `next-intl/link` because of overridden locale option:

```
type Props = Omit<ComponentProps<typeof BaseLink>, 'locale'> & {
  locale?: string;
};
```

PS. Versions I used:

next **v13.4.2** 
next-intl **v2.14.2**

The only solution I found so far (to help the others who faced the same issue) - I extracted that new/overridden props type from the component's parameters (see my comment below).

Would be nice if `next-intl` authors exported that type for us to import, just like we had with the `next/link`. It would make such migrations smoother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using the existing type of react for this purpose:

```
import Link from "next-intl/link";

// use the predefined type from react for this purpose
export type LinkProps = React.ComponentProps<typeof Link>;

// now you can extend it as usual
export interface NavbarItemProps extends LinkProps {
  title: string;
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

to close the gap with a missing type - I just extracted it from the component's parameters:

```
import Link from "next-intl/link"; // this is our new Link that doesn't export LinkProps

// extracting it from the parameters
type LinkProps = Parameters<typeof Link>[0];

// now we can extend it as usual
export interface NavbarItemProps extends LinkProps {
  title: string;
  // ...
}
```